# predefined but empty multidimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a multidimensional array to hold a generated grid.
The problem is I'm used to doing this in java, but doing it in javascript is deceptively harder. I know there are arrays of arrays rather than the standard java style and this is what is causing the confusion.

So in Java I'd expect to do this:

```
private static int[][] anyGrid(int rows, int cols) {
    int[][] grid = new int[rows][cols];
    return grid;
}
```

Say rows and cols were variables of 3. What would happen, is that would create something like this:

grid is:

```
[0,0][0,1][0,2]
[1,0][1,1][1,2]
[2,0][2,1][2,2]
```

But the actual entries would be empty.
So if I wanted to access the first entry I'd do:
`grid[0][0]`, except this would be empty, unless I went `grid[0][0] = 1`; for example.

However doing this in javascript I'm at a loss.

```
var grid = new Array(new Array(cols));
```

Simply produces an array:
grid[0][0]-grid[0][5].
So one array with an internal array of length 6.

Which is.. not quite what I'm after.

How would I make it so that it is empty, but multidimensional beyond the first row?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var grid = [], cols = 3, rows = 4
for (i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    grid.push(new Array(rows))
```

Or swap the `cols` with `rows`.